# The sequence $(a_n)$ is given as $a_1=1, a_{2n} = a_n - 1, a_{2n+1} = a_n + 1$. $a_{2015}=$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, binary

The sequence $(a_n)$ is given as  $a_1=1, a_{2n} = a_n - 1, a_{2n+1} = a_n + 1$.
What's the value of $a_{2015}$

Correct answer should be $a_{2015} = 9$. How?

thing that came to mind was to see what $a_{2015}$ is composed of. So $a_{2015} = a_{(2*1007 + 1)} = a_{1007} + 1$ because $a_{2n+1} = a_n + 1$ and
than to work that way down?

My teacher said that I am complicating too much, and I agree, but
what am I missing to solve this?

Comment: The fact that 2015 in binary is 11111011111, with 10 1's and 1 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think about the procedure that you had in mind. If the binary representation of $n$ ends in $1$, then $n$ is odd; say $n=2k+1$. Then $a_n=a_k+1$, and the binary representation of $k$ is simply what’s left when you drop the last digit of $n$. If the binary representation of $n$ ends in $0$, then $n$ is even; say $n=2k$. Then $a_n=a_k-1$, and again the binary representation of $k$ is simply what’s left when you drop the last digit of $n$. Thus, you’ll add $1$ for every $1$ in the binary representation of $n$, and you’ll subtract $1$ for every $0$.

Write $2015$ in binary: it’s $11111011111$, which has $10$ ones and $1$ zero, so the process will result in $10$ additions of $1$ and one subtraction, for a total of $9$. (You do have to check that setting $a_1=1$ is consistent with this scheme.)

This is the shortcut that your teacher had in mind.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you made a mistake breaking down $a_{2015}$. It should be $a_{2015}=a_{2\times 1007+1}=a_{1007}+1$.

And $a_{1007}=a_{2\times503+1}=a_{503}+1$

$a_{503}=a_{2\times 251+1}=a_{251}+1$

$a_{251}=a_{2\times 125+1}=a_{125}+1$

$a_{125}=a_{2\times 62+1}=a_{62}+1$

$a_{62}=a_{2\times 31+1}=a_{31}-1$

$a_{31}=a_{2\times 15+1}=a_{15}+1$

$a_{15}=a_{2\times 7+1}=a_{7}+1$

$a_{7}=a_{2\times 3+1}=a_{3}+1$

$a_{3}=a_{2\times 1+1}=a_{1}+1$

So, $a_{2015}=a_{1}+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1-1=9$

Comment: Commenting here as well as under the original post:  I think it is worthwhile to point out that what's really happening here is that we are counting 1's and 0's in the binary expansion of 2015, which is 11111011111.

Comment: That was a typo, thank you. That was my first idea, but it seemed like to much complication. If the index of the element was bigger, let's say $a_{34334}$ is there any quicker way to do it?

Comment: @NafelHekun, I'm sorry to keep beating this drum, but:  the binary expansion of 34334 is 1000011000011110, with 7 1's and 9 0's (if I haven't miscounted), so $a_{34334} = -2$.

Comment: @L Spice, sry just saw the comment. That's amazing, thank you :) It's the stuff like this that makes me love math :)

Comment: @NafelHekun, with all due respect to Kyle (whose answer is certainly correct), you should accept [BrianM.Scott](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1826338/87579)'s answer instead, which goes into more detail than my terse comments.